# After creating the object, they are not white color

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i create object using section GameObject, the object is not created in white color.

[image: not white]

I have tried changing color and light.

I expect that created object will be in white color.  [image: white]

Comment: What does section GameObject mean?

Comment: Section, where you can take some 3D or 2D objects. http://prnt.sc/ox9zj4

Comment: Have you tried adding a directional light and angling it down?

Comment: I don't understand... the pics look fine to me....

Comment: Is the problem that the plane has a texture applied to it?

Comment: Look at the spheres abd cubes on the first picture, the are grey, but they must be white(like on the second picture)

Comment: As you can see, I choose white color, but sphere is gray. http://prnt.sc/oxlo2l

Comment: Sounds like a function of light intensity, color, or distance.

Comment: White is only pure white under very bright light. Try increasing your various environment light intensities, ranges etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recreate scene every time, because I had some troubles with shadows.